# PreferenceActivity in Android

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

How can i find if a Preference has been clicked and take some action accordingly.
In this case i want to logout when a Preference in PreferenceActivity with key logout is clicked.The following code is not working.

```
pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
        {
            if(key.contentEquals("prefLogout"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(PreferenceActivityDemoActivity.this, "Logout clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

xml

```
<PreferenceCategory >

    <Preference android:title=Logout"
        android:key="prefLogout"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

also tried using

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
{
    if(preference.getKey().equals("prefLogout"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(PreferenceActivityDemoActivity.this, "Logout clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

According to your XML it should be `if(key.equals("prefLogout")) {...}`

Comment: i have one CheckedPreference and when changed it is displaying a Toast that the CheckedPreference is changed but not Preference.

Comment: This is what i have done for CheckedPreference    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Remember me"
            android:key="prefRememberMe"
            android:persistent="true"/>                                                                                                              if(key.equals("prefRememberMe"))
    {
     Toast.makeText(PreferenceActivityDemoActivity.this, "Remember me clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Comment: why do you have to use Preference in your XML as opposed to any Preference subclass? I don't know about Preference maybe it's not clickable or something..

Comment: Preference lpref = (Preference)findPreference("prefLogout");
lpref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener()
{   
 @Override
 public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
 {
  Toast.makeText(PreferenceActivityDemoActivity.this, "Logout clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return false;
 }
});                                                                  this solved my problem